# Not differentiating between Action names in url Path - asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes

I am getting really weird routing issues when calling actions in my `APIController`. I have a WebApp, but needed an `APIController` so I added that as well as `WebAPIConfig.cs` to App_start and `Global.asax`.

However, when I try to call different `Actions` inside the `APIController`, it seems to not differentiate between the `Actions` unless I add a parameter. For example, if I call `api/controller/happy` it enters the same `Action` as `api/controller/sad`. It enters the Action that was created first in the Controller.

It makes no sense to me, the Action-names are not being considered in the URL.

my API Controller:

```
public class RegistrationManagerController : ApiController
    {
        EventHelper eh = new EventHelper();

        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult IsUserRegistered(string skypeid)
        {
            var skypeuser = Exist.CheckIfRegistered(skypeid);

            return Ok(skypeuser);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Happy()
        {
            var events = await eh.GetHappyRecent();

            return Ok(events);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Sad()
        {
            var events = await eh.GetSadRecent();

            return Ok(events);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UpdateEvent() //TODO id send in body?
        {
            await eh.Update("id");

            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

My WebAPIConfig.cs:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

My RouteConfig (This is a webapp, not a web API):

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();// New feature
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: See here, looks like your exact problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121152/api-controller-declaring-more-than-one-get-statement

Comment: your routetemplate does not contain the action, just the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routetemplate should be

routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"

Answer (score 0):

WebApi follows REST principals so it doesn't route the same way an MVC Controller routes.

Check out this answer here I think it will help you

[need route for my web api 2 controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41351436/need-route-for-my-web-api-2-controller/41351617#41351617)